# How do I change the appearance of messages in OMNeT++?

Tags: c++, objective-c, oop, omnet++

In the manual it says the following:

> To customize the appearance of messages in the graphical runtime environment, override the getDisplayString() method of cMessage or cPacket to return a display string.

I don't understand what this means. I have custom images and I was able to change the icon of nodes with the line below in my simple module.

```
@display("i=misc/train-stationCopy");
```

I have the line below in my message class but it does not work and generates error

```
@display("i=misc/train");
```

What am I missing? Sorry I'm new to omnet++ and c++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this to your `.msg` file. This will enforce the generation of the `getDisplayString()` function in the `*_msg.h` file.

```
const string displayString @override = "i=misc/train";
```